# Why isn't the JSONP callback function getting invoked?

Tags: ajax, jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

I am trying to use jsonp to access the data at:

https://github.com/users/jbranchaud/contributions_calendar_data

However, none of the solutions I have tried are resulting in either the callback or the success function getting invoked. When I use Chrome/Firefox inspection tools, I can look at the script and see that the response was 200 Ok and that the response text contains the data from the above URL. Nevertheless, neither the callback function nor the success function get called at any point. Any ideas about how to get this to work?

Here is my most recent attempt at getting this to run:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function parseResults(results) {
            console.log('hello function callback.');
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://github.com/users/jbranchaud/contributions_calendar_data',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: true,
            jsonpCallback: 'parseResults',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log('success_function');
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('error with jsonp request');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

When I load the page, I see the 'error with jsonp request' in the console, so there is an error with the ajax request. Ideas of why this request isn't succeeding?

Comment: is there any error in the console, can you add a error callback and check whether it is getting called

Comment: whether parseResults is getting called

Comment: There were no errors in the console, but when I added an error callback to the ajax request, it printed my error message (see updated code)

Comment: Your response does not seems to be a jsonp response

Comment: A jsonp response should be of format `<callbackMethod>(<params>)`. ex `parseResults([["2012/03/01",0],["2012/03/02",1],["2012/03/03",1]])`

Comment: I understand how the response is formatted, but I don't understand why the request is getting an error. Can you explain why this is and how to fix it?

Comment: For `jsonp` to be used the service provider (github) has to support `jsonp` format. If the server does not support there is nothing much you can do about it.

Comment: another point is the resource `https://github.com/users/jbranchaud/contributions_calendar_data` is not part of their API. they supports `jsonp` for the published API

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a standard way to check if jsonp is supported? Are there other approaches to accessing the data at this URL?

Comment: If an api supports jsonp it will be specified it the documentation. Another way is to pass an additional parameter `callback=something`like `url?callback=something` then the response should be `something(...)`. ex: check the response for this https://api.github.com/users/jbranchaud?callback=processResults

Answer (score 0):

In the ajax request, try to set the attribute 'jsonp' to false (**jsonp: false**).

Basically, JQuery generate an automatic function callback name, like this : JQuery1223...34.

In your case, you ,already, explicitly set the jsonpCallback function name. so you have to put jsonp attribut to false.
your code should be like this :

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://github.com/users/jbranchaud/contributions_calendar_data',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'parseResults',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log('success_function');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('error with jsonp request');
        }
    });
```